# Streaming PDF to browser, not working in mobile device

Tags: java, css, google-chrome, mobile, outputstream

OK, so... I didnt notice the problem at first, i could stream my pdf as a byte[] directly to my browser and everything worked fine.

I realized the problem when I was going to try it in the browsers debug section -> under "toggle device mode", suddenly the pdf cannot be streamed to the 
browser anymore(atleast, it cannot be displayed). Here's some of my code:

The PDF output (view_mypdf):

```
req.getResponse().setContentType("application/pdf");
    req.getResponse().getOutputStream().write(delegate.getPdfBytes(), 0, delegate.getPdfBytes().length);
    req.getResponse().getOutputStream().flush();
    req.getResponse().getOutputStream().close();
```

My JSP with the iframe..

```
<iframe src="myurl/Controller?view_mypdf" style="height:300px; width: 300px;" name="iframeId" id="iframeId"></iframe>
```

I am not using any special CSS or JavaScript to do this, maybe i should? anyone has an idea why this doesn't work on a mobile device(google chrome) if it actually works on desktop in chrome?